# How to display WPF overlay on top of DirectX?

Tags: wpf, directx, hook

I learned how to hook into the game EndScene function, but how to host WPF content is something I am trying a very long time to understand.

I am trying to do something like Overwolf, for a specific game (starcraft), I asked their team how they do it, but they didn't give any information.

So I tried to examine what exactly OverwolfLauncher.exe does, and I found it injects 3 dlls:
OWExplorer-2006.dll, OWLog.dll, OWClient.dll.
The first two seem not really important. The third hooks into the game directx or opengl dll,  and their overlay manager does some "magic". And that's only what I was able to understand.

I would be happy if someone could explain me how exactly Overwolf managed to host WPF content as overlay.

There are many questions like this on stackoverflow.
[This one was marked as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388492/wpf-and-directx-game-overlay/4388775#4388775), but the solution seems to be about hosting DirectX **inside** WPF.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376016/rendering-from-wpfs-internals-to-a-directx-application

Comment: I saw this few days ago. The problem is like he said: "The only problem I now have is that I loose all interactivity from my window.". It's like he drawing a screenshot of the app on directx. Overwolf widget keep working the same, I am not sure if they use WPF ingame, because it seems impossible.